# Spamassassin per user databases configuration

Tags: spamassassin

For each e-mail user I want to use his own bayes database.

The databases are located at `/home/spamd/[domain]/[user]`, for example `/home/spamd/example.com/testuser` with 2 files: bayes_seen and bayes_toks.

In `/etc/default/spamassassin` I set `virtual-config-dir`:

```
OPTIONS="--create-prefs --max-children 1 -D --helper-home-dir --virtual-config-dir=/home/spamd/%d/%l -x -u spamd"
```

However, in the log I can see that none of placeholders `%d` and `%l` is working, they are replaced with empty strings:

```
sep 20 12:16:19 DietPi spamd[11167]: config: using "/home/spamd//" for user state dir 
sep 20 12:16:19 DietPi spamd[11167]: bayes: tie-ing toDB file R/O /home/spamd///bayes_toks 
sep 20 12:16:19 DietPi spamd[11167]: bayes: tie-ing to DB file R/O /home/spamd///bayes_seen
```

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I need to specify `-u ${recipient}` parameter for `spamc`, more specifically I use this in `master.cf` for postfix:

```
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -u ${recipient} -f -e
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```